# Format of floated li elements doesn't extend when browser is minimized

Tags: html, css, css-float, wrapper

I've created a navbar using an unordered list. I've also created a wrapper which contains my logo and the navbar links. I want the wrapper to have a minimum width of 960px. When the browser window is fully expanded, it looks fine.

**Fully expanded window**
[image]

When I minimize the window to be narrower than the wrapper, and scroll back over to the end of the navbar, the formatting on the navbar (which is just a background color) is lost. Something similar happens to the header.

**Minimized window**
[image]

How can I get the header pawprint image and the orange background color on the ul to extend to the right side of the window, while still keeping my wrapper at a minimum width of 960px?

I've tried "overflow-x: auto" on my #nav id and on the header, which extended the formatting but, obviously, created scrollbars and other unwanted quirks.

I gather my problem has something to do with the li elements being floated, and attempted a clearfix, but either I did it wrong or it didn't work.

I'm looking for a solution using just HTML and CSS, ideally. Even so, I gather that flexbox may be a solution, but I was hoping to avoid having to dive into flexbox just yet. But if I have to, I will.

My code is below. Any help is appreciated!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-width: 1px;
}

#nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: -2.25em 0;
  background-color: rgba(240, 100, 60, 1);
  height: 2em;
  cursor: default;
}

#nav li {
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  width: 8em;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  background-image: url('../images/Asset%202.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="styles/stack-overflow-style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img id="logo" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4e/de/bc/4edebc3259e32539dd6d6d29d5d8474a.jpg" alt="Good Boy Dog Care Logo">
    </div>
    <ul id="nav">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Services</li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you can do is to set the custom styling for the mimimized browser width, have a look at the code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1700px) and (max-width: 1998px) {
    //your modified styling for the minimized window size goes here
}
```

and you can get the width of minimized window by using the following javascript function:

```
alert($(window).width());
```